# How to decript AES having part of the message? (with key)

Tags: encryption, aes

How can we decrypt message (if possible) having part of original message, part of encoded text, IV and key? Assume, we have only one block.

**Example:**

- IV = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
- original text =
  __ __ __ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
- encripted text = XX YY ZZ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __

(we don't know __ bytes, but we know key)
Additionally, known byte count from original and encriptrd texts will always be 16

**Edit:**
All previous blocks (encrypted) are known. Initial chaining mode is CBC, but we can decode all previous blocks with given key and IV. This would be the last one.

This is why we can assume, that we have only one block and chaining is ECB.

Comment: You also need to know the block mode used for the cipher and - assuming CBC/PCBC, CFB or OFB, you'll need at the very least the first block.

Comment: @zwer it is not the "the first block" that is needed, it is the previous block that is needed.

Comment: 24 bits are unknown and can be very easily brute-forced. The issue is that it is not guaranteed that what you get is the actual value. You will need to brute-force the whole 24 bit space and check if there are more than one ciphertexts that fit the expected ciphertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to decrypt a portion of CBC mode encrypted data the prior encrypted block is needed. See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

On encryption it is the previous block's encrypted data that is xor'ed with the plain text. In the case of the first block it is the IV that is xor'ed with the data.